# Unable to click dropdown when using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to help download files. I run into an issue where I cannot click on this dropdown menu. I have tried searching ID and xpath, but python is spitting out 'no such element' error.

XPATH below:

`//*[@id="ReportViewerCtl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImg"]`

HTML:

`<img id="ReportViewerCtl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImg" src="/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.Export.gif" alt="Export drop down`

Have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ReportViewerCtl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImg").click() 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReportViewerCtl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImg"]').click()
```

Thank you in advance for all of the help! Just getting started with python.

Comment: did you tried wait and checked whether element is inside iframe ?

Comment: That was it, thank you!